# Perl: Why is this expression not working with the new version of Perl?

Tags: perl

I am attempting to run a Perl script, which produces the following error:

> Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*)\$ENV{ <-- HERE (.*)}(.*)$/ at /root/cesm1_2_0/scripts/ccsm_utils/Case.template/ConfigCase.pm line 1180.
>   Compilation failed in require at ./create_newcase line 361

The offending code is:

```
if($text =~/^(.*)\$ENV{(.*)}(.*)$/){
    ...
}
```

There was an issue earlier in the code that was due to "using a newer Perl version than that code supports" (see: https://bb.cgd.ucar.edu/machine-configuration-and-generating-domain-file), so I expect that the regex syntax in Perl has changed.

Can someone translate this line to be compatible with the current version of Perl?

Comment: Changelog entry: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5260delta.pod#Unescaped-literal-%22%7B%22-characters-in-regular-expression-patterns-are-no-longer-permissible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{` is now always treated as a regex metacharacter. When an unescaped character is illegal, you make it legal by escaping it.

```
$text =~/^(.*)\$ENV\{(.*)}(.*)$/
                   ^---- new character
```

See [https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5260delta.pod#Unescaped-literal-"{"-characters-in-regular-expression-patterns-are-no-longer-permissible](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5260delta.pod#Unescaped-literal-"%7B"-characters-in-regular-expression-patterns-are-no-longer-permissible)

Comment: *Almost* always, as the page you linked to describes - `qr/{fee|{fie/` is still allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
if ($text =~/^(.*)\$ENV\{(.*)\}(.*)$/) {
```